# If I mark a method as Obsolete["...", true], what should be the return value? An arbitrary value?

Tags: c#, .net, deprecated, obsolete

I have a method that is being made obsolete (in fact completely unsupported) because the underlying concept is being removed. So, the method can't have any implementation and I made it `throw new NotSupportedException()`. Does it make sense to also cause a compilation error with the `error` parameter for `Obsolete` attribute? Or if I'm going to do that, should I just return an arbitrary value (since the method will never be run)? Can someone explain or link me to documentaiton of best practice?

Comment: You don't have to return anything if you throw `NotSupportedException`. That seems like the best idea to me.

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't change implementation of `[Obsolete]` method to always throw exception.

you are defeating whole purpose of this attribute, you will mark method that is working, as obsolete that means you no longer garauntee that in your next releases of your API that method will exist.

while method is marked as obsolete, other developers have some time to work on their code and cope with new changes. instead of just having their code broken up.

if you are going to throw exception always, you better remove that entirely, or have same implementation but mark it as `[Obsolete]` and remove it completely when its appropriate.

[from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22kk2b44(v=vs.90).aspx)

> The Obsolete attribute marks a program entity as one that is **no longer recommended for use**. Each use of an entity marked obsolete will subsequently generate a warning or an error

did it say it always throw exception and its doesn't work anymore? nope. if your method doesn't work anymore, you made a breaking change so you have to either make it somehow work and mark it as obsolete, or remove it completely.

Another good point,

> The Obsolete attribute can be used without arguments, but including an explanation of why the item is obsolete and what to use instead is recommended.

Comment: `Obsolete[.., true]` generates a compilation error, "Each use of an entity marked obsolete will subsequently generate a warning **or an error**". Therefore, "did it say it always throw exception and its doesn't work anymore?" - Pretty much, yes, except it's a compile time error. That *is* a breaking change using only the `[Obsolete]` attribute. So if you're doing that, you might as well remove the implementation. An exception seems reasonable since you have to throw or return something, and that way even if someone uses reflection shenanigans to call your method, they get a runtime exception.

Comment: just removing the method is your worst option IMO. Any existing assembly that calls into that method will now produce a runtime error that may demand a lot of effort from the developer to figure out why that is happening; btoh, if you *throw* an exception you can have a much better error message and call stacks pointing to which code is calling the obsolete method. Anyway, I usually follow this sequence when obsoleting APIs: *production* -> *Obsolete(warning)* (type/method still works) -> *Obsolete(error)* (member body throws exception with good message) -> *removal*